# How to manually select an (Ultra) ListView item

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, infragistics

I am trying to manually select an item within a UltraListView control using the following line of code:

```
lvwSomethings.SelectedItems.Add(lvwSomethings.Items.Cast<UltraListViewItem>()
.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SubItems["Id"].Value.Equals(_selectedId)));
```

However, if the _SelectedId is not found in the list, I get the following error:

**An UltraListViewItem cannot be selected if it does not belong to this control's Items collection**

How can I have it so that it selects the first item in the list if the '_selectedId' does not exist?

Comment: Do you need to write it in a single line? What about getting the id first and then add an if to check the condition?

Comment: @Steve I had initially written it the way you described, but was interested to see if it is possible to write it in one line. I am under the impression this is faster than having a for loop and then an if condition!

Comment: Well, you don't need to write a loop (explicitly) but simple check for null on the result of firstordefault. I will try to add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your one line in two and add a check if FirstOrDefault return a null (no such item in the subitems collection)

```
UltraListViewItem item;
item = lvwSomethings.Items.Cast<UltraListViewItem>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.SubItems["Id"].Value.Equals(_selectedId))

if(item != null)
   lvwSomethings.SelectedItems.Add(item);
```